# Check if a SQLite record is older than certain time

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have records in my SQLite database and I'd like to check if a certain record is older than a certain amount of hours (or minutes or seconds).

I couldn't find a function to calculate "age()" in SQLite (like they have in Postgres). Does it exist?

If not, I was already trying to extract the epoch of the record (works fine) and was thinking to compare that with the epoch of the current time. But I can't find a function that will simply return me the epoch of the current timestamp. Can anybody help?

(Note: I did check SimpleDateFormat, currenttimemillis() etc, but didn't seem to do what I want or I'm missing something)

Comment: Have you considered a datetime column for your record?

Comment: Quintin, I'd be happy to put a datetime in my record, but even then, I don't see how I can calculate the time that passed between it's "last_updated" field and the current time. Can you please explain?

Comment: Meaning how to do it in pure sql and not using java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to retrieve difference between current time and "last_updated" only by SQL language:

```
SELECT strftime('%s','now','localtime')-strftime('%s','2011-08-18 22:49:00') as date;
```

This SQL statement will return me difference between current time and `2011-08-18 22:49:00`. Instead of `2011-08-18 22:49:00` you can pass `last_updated` column name and it should return you difference between them.

You can read more [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: I'll check your query. I had tried my own: select min(last_updated), strftime(\"%s\", 'now') - strftime(\"%s\", min(last_updated)) from forecasts, but that does not retun anything in column with index 1, though it does return "8/18/11 8:05 PM"

Comment: Found out that the problem with my query was related to the formatting of the datetime in my fields. Now it works like a charm.